Why is this representation abelian?
In Serre's "Abelian $\ell$-adic representation" (pg. II-18), he constructs a $\mathbb{Q}$-algebraic group $S_m$. Let $S_m(\mathbb{Q}_{\ell})$ denote the set of $\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}$ rational points of $S_m$ and let $S_{m/\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}}=S_m \times_{\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}} \mathbb{Q}_{\ell}$.  Let $V_{\ell}$ be a finite-dimensional $\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}$-vector space. He then constructs an abelian $\ell$-adic representation of $K$ in $V_{\ell}$
$$\phi_{\ell}:\operatorname{Gal}(K^{ab}/K) \rightarrow S_m(\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}) \rightarrow \operatorname{Aut}V_{\ell}.$$
I want to know why this representation is abelian (i.e., $\phi_{\ell}(\operatorname{Gal}(K^{ab}/K))$ is abelian)?
$\operatorname{Aut} V_{\ell}$ would be abelian if and only if $V_{\ell}$ is one dimensional over $\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}$ so that doesn't help. If $S_m(\mathbb{Q}_{\ell})$ were abelian, we would be done because $S_m(\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}) \rightarrow \operatorname{Aut} V_{\ell}$ is a homomorphism, but I am not sure if that is true. So I am unsure how Serre makes this claim. Any help would be appreciated!

I’m not sure I understand your question. If I recall correctly, $S_m$ is a commutative group scheme, so any morphism $G_K \rightarrow S_m(\mathbb{Q}_{\ell})$ factors through $Gal(K^{ab}/K)$?

@Aphelli I am sorry I am not familiar with algebraic geometry so don't actually know what a group scheme is :(

@Aphelli Are you trying to say that because $Gal(K^{ab}/K)$ is abelian, and $\phi$ is a homomorphism, its image would be abelian?

Never mind schemes here, it’s just that IIRC $S_m$ is commutative by construction. So what I’m saying is that because $S_m$ is abelian, any morphism from any group $G$ to $S_m$ factors through the quotient $G \rightarrow G^{ab}$. If $G$ is the absolute Galois group of some number field $K$, then $G^{ab}$ identifies with $Gal(K^{ab}/K)$.

The construction of $S_m$ proceeds by "enlarging" the Torus group which is just the Weil restriction of $\mathbb{G}m$. I am not entirely sure why the $\mathbb{Q}{\ell}$ rational points of $S_m$ would be abelian then?

Serre says more or less that $S_m$ is commutative by construction, see Remark 2) page II-5. In fact, he states it outright at the very beginning of Chapter II, before the preliminaries.

I see, that is very helpful of you, thank you so very much!!! :)
